# phonegap iphone : Documents Directory Absolute path

Tags: ios, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap and I am using it with Xcode.

Can anybody tell me how to get to the absolute path of the Documents Directory in the index.html?

Answer (score 2):

```
function success(fileSystem) {
    var path = fileSystem.root.fullPath;
}

// request the persistent file system
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, null);
```

`path` should point to `/Documents`.