# iOS 6 local storage file appears twice

Tags: ios, ios6, sencha-touch, local-storage, sencha-touch-2.1

I have an app that uses local storage (using sencha 'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage')  to view some content offline. I was rejected by itunes for violating the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

I thought it might be related to the localStorage being inside the /Documents folder in iOS before iOS 5.1. To confirm that in newer versions the document folder is empty I checked, but I still found a .file__0.localstorage.

The strange think is that the same file (but without the leading dot) also exists in the library/caches folder, where it should be.

Both have the same content.

Does anyone know how this can happen? I already asked in the Sencha Support but it does not seem to be related to the Sencha framework.

Note: I am not using PhoneGap, only Sencha.

Comment: How are you wrapping your application to upload to the app store? are you using just a plain UIWebView?

Comment: I´m using sencha packaging which is using a plain UIWebView afaik

Comment: iTunes finally has approved the app but without doing any changes except setting the app for iOS >=5.1 instead of supporting older versions. They gave no more explanation.

Comment: @Sadako For god sake,please help me out on how to save the DB file to documents directory using sencha touch,we are not able to access the documents path at all,we followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608767/phonegap-iphone-documents-directory-absolute-path) link.Please help me,please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a very small Hello World Application with Sencha that writes to local storage I could reproduce this behavior. It seems like on application exit, it will write a copy of the localstorage file to the /Documents folder.

This seemed suspicious to me and it reminded me of the PhoneGap patch for iOS 5.1 that backs up the localStorage file also.

With iOS 5.1 Apple started to put the localStorage file in the Library/Caches folder which broke many applications because the data was no longer reliable stored. So PhoneGap and others started to implement Workarrounds that backup the localStorage file to the documents folder and automatically restore it if needed.

Trying to find proof that Sencha does something similar, I opened up the resulting .app package and found a stbuild_template file that contains the native wrapper code. It is of course compiled, but searching for the string "localStorage" results in some interesting results like:

```
restoreLocalStorage
preserveLocalStorage
Could not remove source file while backing up localstorage Could not copy localstorage backup . Caches WebKit/LocalStorage .file__0.localstorage file__0.localstorage
SNLocalStoreageFix
```

Also I found a lot of references to NimbleKit which seems to be used internally for the packaging.

This thread also hints at a solution for the iOS 5.1 local storage problem in Sencha Touch 2.1 which is what the OP is using: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194674-Localstorage-and-native-iOS-5.1-apps&s=04149e771f9c4eea15cb6f6d97069ff6

All this is evidence for me that Sencha implemented a workarround for iOS 5.1 which will put the localStorage in the /Documents folder. Since you only use the localStorage file for caching, Apple rejected you because you store non-user data in /Documents.

I think using PhoneGap there is an option to disable this backup. So you might want to consider using this or ask Sencha if they have a similar option to disable it.

Comment: I have asked sencha: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?253638-Disable-backup-of-localStorage-file-in-Documents-folder but i don´t have yet any answer. For now PhoneGap is my best chance